# Browser Link not working with Web Application from ASP.NET 5 Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1 installed in my Windows 8.1 machine. When I try to create and run new `"Project"` `(File->New->Project->MVC)` under `ASP.NET 4.5.2 Templates` I find Refresh Linked Browsers `(Ctrl+Alt+Enter)` option working and enabled. While trying to create and run new `"Project"` `(File->New->Project->Web Application)` under `ASP.NET 5 Templates` I find Refresh Linked Browsers option disabled. Is there something wrong with new version or browser link is not supported by the new version?